# Check if other locale exists

Tags: localization, conditional

I have just one page on my site with only one language:

[image]

Every other page has two languages.

I want to disable certain things on that page (like language switchers). How do I determine this?

This just returns all avalable languages no matter what languages are activated:

```
{% set otherLocales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds() %}
  {% for locale in otherLocales %}
    {{ locale }}
  {% endfor %}
```

I tried to do it with status:

```
{% set otherLocales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds().status('live') %}
```

but that returns an error as well. I tried `status` because it's labeled that way in the cp.

This returns the opposite language although the other locale doesn't exist on this page.

```
{% set otherLocales = craft.i18n.getSiteLocaleIds()|without(craft.locale) %}
{% for locale in otherLocales %}
  {{ locale }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try this: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/show-entry-content-for-other-available-locales?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query for the same entry in another locale by explicitly setting the locale parameter.

```
{% set de = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('de').first() %}
{% set en = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('en').first() %}

German:  {{ de ? 'OK' : 'nope' }}
English: {{ en ? 'OK' : 'nope' }}
```